# How to turn Pandas' DataFrame.groupby() result into MultiIndex

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a set of measurements that were obtained by varying two parameters, `knob_b` and `knob_2` (in practice there are a lot more):

```
data = np.empty((6,3), dtype=np.float)
data[:,0] = [3,4,5,3,4,5]
data[:,1] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
data[:,2] = np.random.random(6)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['knob_1', 'knob_2', 'signal'])
```

i.e., `df` is

```
   knob_1  knob_2    signal
0       3       1  0.076571
1       4       1  0.488965
2       5       1  0.506059
3       3       2  0.415414
4       4       2  0.771212
5       5       2  0.502188
```

Now, considering each parameter on its own, I want to find the minimum value that was measured for each setting of this parameter (ignoring the settings of all other parameters). The pedestrian way of doing this is:

```
new_index = []
new_data = []
for param in df.columns:
    if param == 'signal':
        continue
    group = df.groupby(param)['signal'].min()
    for (k,v) in group.items():
        new_index.append((param, k))
        new_data.append(v)
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index,
                                      names=('parameter', 'value'))
df2 = pd.Series(index=new_index, data=new_data)
```

resulting `df2` being:

```
parameter  value
knob_1     3        0.495674
           4        0.277030
           5        0.398806
knob_2     1        0.485933
           2        0.277030
dtype: float64
```

Is there a better way to do this, in particular to get rid of the inner loop?

It seems to me that the result of the `df.groupby` operation already has everything I need - if only there was a way to somehow create a `MultiIndex` from it without going through the list of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `keys` argument of `pd.concat()`:

```
pd.concat([df.groupby('knob_1')['signal'].min(),
           df.groupby('knob_2')['signal'].min()],
          keys=['knob_1', 'knob_2'],
          names=['parameter', 'value'])
```